# Change z-index value of a particular class through Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, node.js

How to change Z-index value from 3 to 0, as below example. It's in inline css. I only have to change z-index value for particular class only. It should be in JS however complete code is written in ES6.

```html
<div class="xyz" style="position:absolute;z-index:3;top:0;left:0;">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change the z-index of multiple div using javascript or jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30077134/1529630) and [How can I select all elements with the same class name?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16985841/1529630)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelector(".xyz").style.zIndex = 0
```

This will change z-index for the first element with class `xyz`. If you want to change it for all elements with that class, use `document.querySelectorAll()` and loop through the elements:

```
for (const element of document.querySelectorAll(".xyz")) {
  element.style.zIndex = 0
}
```