# How do I differentiate between buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, button, instagram, greasemonkey

I don't know anything about writing code but I'm trying to write a script to automatically block people on Instagram but I'm having trouble because the report button and block buttons have the same name.

`<button class="aOOlW -Cab_   " tabindex="0">Report User</button>`

`<button class="aOOlW -Cab_   " tabindex="0">Block this user</button>`

If I use "aOOlW -Cab_" then it just clicks the report button over and over again and if I use the whole class then it doesn't click on anything.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Give them `id` attributes just like you did class names. The `id` attributes have to be unique

Comment: try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985841/how-can-i-select-all-elements-with-the-same-class-name) hope this will try to solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for the correct button by checking for the text of each button with something like this:

```
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("aOOlW");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  if (btns[i].innerHTML == "Block this user") {
    btns[i].click();
  }
}
```

This is assuming the buttons aren't a part of your own code.  If they are a part of your own code, you can just add id tags to them like this:

```
<button class="aOOlW -Cab_   " id="report" tabindex="0">Report User</button>
<button class="aOOlW -Cab_   " id="block"  tabindex="0">Block this user</button>
```

And get the correct button with:

```
document.getElementById("block");
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers, Austin Adams answer worked for me. Now is there any way to set this so it only clicks the button once?